# Find if windows installer succeeds or fails

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I want to send my users a package of 3 applications (each of them are an exe file that can be installed) for them to download and install.
These packages are depended to each other so for example to install the second package the first installation file should get installed properly. Is there a way to find out if the windows installer fails during the installation? (By Failure i mean: User cancels the installation - error in installation - driver installation problem or anything that leads to failure of the installation)

Comment: You say that the 3 app installers are .EXEs, but then you say you're using Windows Installer . . . Windows Installer packages aren't .EXEs, they're .MSIs.  Can you be a little more specific?  Are you using InstallShield and wrapping the .MSI in a SETUP.EXE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the install packages with msiexec and creating a log file:

```
msiexec /i InstallPackage.msi /log log.txt
```

In Windows-Installer packages you can use Conditions to check if a package could be installed.